# regex matching letters and digits with signs

Tags: regex, preg-match

With PHP's `preg_match`, I try to match element symbols as

- K+ => `array( [0] => K+, [1] => K, [2] => +)`
- Cr7+ => `array( [0] => Cr7+, [1] => Cr, [2] => 7+)`
- O2- => `array( [0] => O2-, [1] => O, [2] => 2-)`

I came up with a regex of

```
preg_match('/^[A-Za-z](\d[+|-])/', $str, $match);
```

but it does not match `K+`. How can I add OR condition to the digit too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match an uppercase letter following optional lowercase letters indicating an element name that end to digits or `[-+]` signs or both using:

```
([A-Z][a-z]*)(\d*[-+]?)
```

[RegEx live demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gqu5sl/1)

PHP code (see demo [here](https://3v4l.org/jGpYf)):

```
preg_match_all('~([A-Z][a-z]*)(\d*[-+]?)~', $str, $matches);
```

Output for the provided input:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => K+
            [1] => K
            [2] => +
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Cr7+
            [1] => Cr
            [2] => 7+
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => O2-
            [1] => O
            [2] => 2-
        )

)
```